# Proof of an inequality in Sobolev space.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I want to show the next inequality:

$$\| D^a u D^b v \|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)} \leq C \| u \|_{H^s(R^n)} \| v \|_{H^s(R^n)}$$
(for $s>n/2$) Where $D$ is a differential operator.

What I did so far is to write the next stuff:

$$\| D^a u D^b v \|_{L^2} = \| \hat{(D^a u D^b v)} \|_{L^2} = \| \hat{D^a u} * \hat{D^b v} \|_{L^2}$$

But how to proceed from there?
(I used Parseval identity and the fourier transform of multiplication equals the convolution of fourier transforms).

Comment: What are $a$ and $b$? What is the order of $D$?

Comment: a and b satisfy $|a|+|b| \leq s$.

Comment: $D$ is the differential operator, i.e: $D^b = \frac{\partial^{|b|}}{\partial x_1^{a_1}\cdots \partial x_n^{a_n}}$, where $|b|=a_1+\cdots+ a_n$.

Answer (score 0):

An outline:

If $s-|a|>n/2$ or $s-|b|>n/2$ then we're done since, in the first case, we get $D^a u\in L^{\infty}$ with appropriate control by Sobolev embedding.

If $s-|a|, s-|b|<n/2$, then again by Sobolev embedding we get that $D^a u\in L^p$ for every $p\in [2, 2^*_a]$, where $2^*_a:=2n/(n-2(s-|a|))$, and similarly for $b$. The desired inequality then follows from Hölder's inequality since $1/2^*_a+1/2^*_b<1/2$ (since $|a|+|b|\leq s$).

If $s-|a|=n/2$ then $D^a u\in L^p$ for every $p\in [2,\infty)$, and we proceed as before.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to prove this claim with a similar argument as in the proof that sobolev space is a banach algebra which timur provided in math.stackexchange?

Comment: Which proposition are you quoting as in "Sobolev embedding"?